# idiomatic file locking in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have a group of futures processing jobs from a queue that involve writing to files. What's the idiomatic way to make sure only one future accesses a particular file at a time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using agents instead of locks to ensure this?

I think using agents to safe guard shared mutable state, regardless if it's in memory or on disk is more idiomatic in clojure than using locks.

If you create one agent at a time and send the access tries to the agents, you can ensure that only on thread at time accesses a given file.

For example like this:

```
(use 'clojure.contrib.duck-streams)

(defn file-agent [file-name]
  (add-watch (agent nil) :file-writer 
    (fn [key agent old new] 
      (append-spit file-name new))))

(defn async-append [file-agent content]
  (send file-agent (constantly content)))
```

then append your file through the agent:

```
(async-append "content written to file" (file-agent "temp-file-name"))
```

If you need synchronous usage of the file it could be achieved with await. Like this:

```
(defn sync-append [file-agent content]
  (await (send file-agent (constantly content))))
```

Comment: Neat! It took a bit to get my head around this. I had ended up using a ref to a map that contained an entry for each open file. Your solution looks like it could be much nicer.

Comment: I'm still unclear on something - if two threads both call async-append and pass in the same file-name, what's to keep them both from opening the file? It seems the call to file-agent within async-append would create a unique agent for each thread, right?

Comment: Sorry for unclear instructions, I meant to create one file-agent per file and then append it it either through async-append or sync-append depending whetever you need asynchronous or synchronous appending. You could keep the agents them selves maybe in a map to find the correct agent.

Comment: And of course if you need only synchronous access it might be better to use ref's or atom's in a similar way with a watch. This time the used mutable state entity should probably keep whole contents of the file instead of the patch info. This could be useful tho if you need to do the changes based on the current contents. Same can of course be done with agents too if you need nicer function based change of the files and asynchronous access.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the core Clojure function [locking](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/locking) which is used as follows:

```
(locking some-object
  (do-whatever-you-like))
```

Here `some-object` could either be the file itself, or alternatively any arbitrary object that you want to synchronise on (which might make sense if you wanted a single lock to protect multiple files).

Under the hood this uses standard JVM object locking, so it's basically equivalent to a synchronized block of code in Java.

Comment: How do you make sure that you actually lock the file if you get two different file objects (or tow different String objects) pointing to the same file?

Comment: There are various options. Using a Singleton is fine if you don't care about heavy concurrent workloads. Use interning or a hash map to ensure a unique String name for each file used if you want concurrent access to many files in parallel. Or just ensure you don't create duplicate objects pointing to the same file in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions - using String/intern is what I've used recently. But my point was that your example might be misleading since the question uses `file-name` in which case it wouldn't work properly; maybe update your answer? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is specific built-in function for this in Clojure but you can use standard java IO functions to do this.  This would look something like this:

```
(import '(java.io File RandomAccessFile))

(def f  (File. "/tmp/lock.file"))
(def channel (.getChannel (RandomAccessFile. f "rw")))
(def lock (.lock channel))
(.release lock)
(.close channel)
```

Comment: I checked out this avenue first, but unfortunately this method is only useful for locking the file from access by other processes. When working with multiple threads in the same VM, lock and tryLock will both throw an exception if another thread in the same VM already has the file locked, rather than blocking until the file is available.